# Why Bootstrap col-xs- "Horizontal at all times"?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datagrid

In Bootstrap document, in the size of "Extra small devices Phones (<768px)", the grid system behave "Horizontal at all times".

I don't understand this, as in, why it is horizontal? If the screen is super small, shouldn't it be all vertically stacked? so user will be easier to scroll vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Well for small screen size you use 'col-sm-xx', col-xs-ss'. This will make sure your content goes horizontally. However if you have an image for instance which is big, then it will go down vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the opposite. From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)..

> Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the
>   extra small .. grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .. to
>   your columns.

So the `col-xs-*` **prevents stacking** and keeps the columns across horizontally. All the other grid tiers (sm,md,lg) will stack vertically at a specific "breakpoint".

- The `sm` tier stacks at 768px
- The `md` tier stacks at 992px
- The `lg`
  tier stacks at 1200px

**[Grid tiers demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/hw5SAYJXnz)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<div class = "row">
  <!--Remember, in bootstrap rows the cols have to add up to 12-->
  <div class = "col-md-6">

  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-6">

  </div>
</div>
```

Whatever is inside the col-md-6 will take half the screen on a medium+ device, on a smaller screen, it will go vertically.